# SQL Server Domain Authentication over VPN

Tags: sql-server, ssms, vpn

I have a user with SSMS installed locally who wants to be able to access the SQL Db on a remote server over SonicWall SSL VPN.

He can connect to the VPN just fine, RDP to SQL server (as a test) just fine, but cannot connect with SSMS to the server.

So far I've tried:

1. Enabling Trust for the connection as it was at first presenting an SSL error. Now we just get "login failed for user" errors.
2. Tested his user with Windows Authentication on the server directly, it works fine.
3. Enabling names pipes and TCP/IP in server configuration manager.
4. Testing logging in with a SQL authentication user over VPN - This also works fine.
5. I am sure the domain\username and password are correct and verified them in several other ways.
6. Checked the SQL server properties and Allow remote connections is enabled with no timeout.
7. Opened up everything in the sonicwall from the SSLVPN to the SQL server as a test, changed nothing.
8. Attempted disabling the local and SQL windows firewall, changed nothing.
9. Probably some other stuff, but I don't remember right now.

This is SQL Server 2014. He is using SSMS 2017, but I've tried it on the SQL Server with 2017 and it works fine and as mentioned he can log in over VPN with a direct SQL Server user. All other users just RDP to SQL server and connect that way so this has never come up again, but they don't want the new employee having RDP access to the SQL Server.

The exact settings on his SSMS I'm using are Active Directory - Password and under connection properties encrypt connect and trust server certificate are checked.

No special or changed ports on SQL Server, everything is basic installation defaults.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm editing the **NT Service\MSSQLSERVER** user.

However, when you edit the user/s in question and navigate to **User Mapping** as can be seen below:

[image: Security Login]

Is the Database they are allowed to access selected?

Also, while the Database is selected, did you tick the permissions to the Database, as stipulated above?

If not, please try this and advise if it worked?